# fortran90: addressing memory location

Tags: c, pointers, fortran90, memory-address

I have a fortran90 code to optimize.
Now I'd like to access memory location of a structure in an external loop, and then access the deepest structure in a nested loop.
Something like this:

## sample fortran loop - legacy version

```
do i = 1, N
  ii = some integer
  jj = some other integer
  do j = 1, M
    c = a(ii, jj)%b(i)
  enddo
enddo
```

has to become:

## second fortran loop - what I would like to write

```
do i = 1, N
  ii = some integer
  jj = some other integer
  pointertoa = &a(ii, jj) !I know it's not correct in fortran, that is the question!
  do j = 1, M
    c = pointertoa%b(i)
  enddo
enddo
```

I have this (sample) C code working as I expect:

## Working memory addressing in C

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct mem{
  int a;
    struct mm{
    int b;
    float v;
  } mmm;
};

void main(){

  struct mem *m, dum;

  dum.a = 12;
  dum.mmm.b = 5;
  dum.mmm.v = 3.2;

  m = &dum; //m is given dum memory address

  printf("dum.a = %d\n", dum.a);
  printf("dum.mmm.b = %d\n", dum.mmm.b);
  printf("dum.mmm.v = %f\n", dum.mmm.v);

  printf("m.a = %d\n", m->a);
  printf("m.mmm.b = %d\n", m->mmm.b);
  printf("m.mmm.v = %f\n", m->mmm.v);

}
```

A couple of question:

1. How would you do the same I did in C in fortran90?
2. Do you think the second fortran loop would speed up the code?

Comment: Regarding (2) how would it possibly speed up the code?

Comment: A pointer in Fortran is set by `=>` instead of `&`!

Comment: @JohnZwinck, the speedup would be a sort of _prefetching_: you can see the `ii` and `jj` indexes are stored in the external cycle, so it would be obvious to load `a(ii, jj)` at the same place.
@AlexanderVogt, a pointer simply won't work, since I need the memory location of a(ii, jj) in the internal cycle, not a reference to its value - anyway, I tried with a pointer in the C code, getting a set fault :).

Comment: @bio, the compilers are not dumb, first demonstrate this is indeed slowing the code and only after that optimize.

Comment: Well, what I say seems uncorrect: the reason why I get a se**g** fault is that I didn't allocate `*m` before writing `*m = dum`.
This code produces correct output:
`m =  malloc(sizeof (struct mem));
  *m = dum;`
Thanks!

Comment: Always use tag [tag:fortran] and only add the version when necessary to distinguish that your question is specific. For example that you cannot use Fortran 2008 but only Fortran 90.

Answer (score 3):

Fortran will make it very very difficult for you to get the memory address of a variable or anything else for that matter.  The tricks and techniques you may have learned in C, messing around with pointers and memory addresses, just aren't supported in Fortran.  Nor, generally, are they needed within Fortran's core application domains.  Your question rather suggests you are trying to write C in Fortran.  Don't.

Now I've got that off my chest, you may be able to achieve what you want using the recently-introduced `associate` construct.  Something like

```
  associate(pointertoa => a(ii, jj)) 
  do j = 1, M
    c = pointertoa%b(i)
  enddo
  end associate
```

Whether this achieves your efficiency goals I haven't a scooby.  But I'll be surprised if it does.  Optimising access to array elements is something that Fortran compilers have been working on for 50+ years and they're really quite good at it.

EDIT, in response to OP's first comment ...

If your compiler supports `associate` you can certainly use it.  But if someone is going to look over your shoulder and hit you painfully on the head if you use any feature introduced to Fortran after publication of the 90 standard then it's up to you whether or not you take the hit.  The compiler ain't going to care, nor is the compiled code.  `associate` is part of the standard and Fortran has a very good record of maintaining backwards compatibility so the likelihood that a future compiler will get upset is very small.

In writing your C function don't forget to take advantage of loop unrolling, memory prefetching, multiple instruction pipelines, vector operations, common subexpression elimination, all that sort of shit.  If you manage to write a C function that outperforms the product of a Fortran compiler with optimisation turned up to 11 come back with the data to prove it and I'll eat my hat.

And, while I'm writing again, I note that the loop

```
  do j = 1, M
    c = pointertoa%b(i)
  enddo
```

is almost entirely redundant and a good optimising compiler would just create code to execute `c = pointertoa%b(i)` once.

Comment: It seems `associate` is something introduced in **fortran 2003**..
and unfortunately I have to optimise a **fortran90** code! Can I use it anyway in fortran90?
I think I'll try and write an external C function to do the job.
About efficiency, you're right about compilers' smartness, but as I replied to previous comments, I would have `M` loads less if I do as I would like to.

Comment: You can also just use the Fortran 90 pointer: `type(xx), ponter :: pointertoa; pointertoa => a(ii, jj)`, but I would actually expect decrease of the code efficiency, not increase. The compilers are clever enough to find that they do not have to compute the address of `a(ii, jj)` more than once themselves.

Comment: @HPM, really many thanks. I used Fortran 90 pointers as Vladimir suggested, and I got no significative improvement. Still have to read the optimisation report (using ifort 15 with -O3 flag), but surely I have no speedup.
Of course I'm using any kind of techniques to speed up this code, and already saw a real improvement with vectorisation flags for example, but then I decided to do a step back and see if the serial-scalar code is the best I can have.
You can leave your hat on :)